# Mercurial: How can I create an unplanned branch

Tags: mercurial, branch, commit

My use case is this:

I am working on a new feature and I have several commits on that feature.
Since it was a minor feature, I didn't even consider doing the feature in a feature branch.

However. Now my boss comes along and tells me to fix a bug on the same branch that I am working on (default).

To fix that I'd like to create a feature branch for my feature, push all my existing (unpushed) commits into that branch.

So I'd like to create a branch just before my first commit and then somehow move all my commits to that branch.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s two ways to approach this, depending on your preference:

1. In a new repository.

   Make a new clone of your repository, and do the bug fix you need to make there. Then push it to the main repository when you’re done, and continue where you left off in the original repository. Pull and merge to get the new changes as usual.
2. In the existing repository.

   Update to the changeset before your local changes, and just start fixing and committing there. This creates a new anonymous branch. When you’re done, push using `push -r .`, this will only push the changes that are included in the working copy. After this, merge with your original branch (`hg merge`) and continue where you left off.

   Note that you can bookmark the feature branch with `hg bookmark` if you do not feel comfortable with leaving your changes unlabeled. Also you can easily find back any heads you left behind using `hg heads`.

Personally I prefer to work in a new clean clone, as you don’t need to worry about branching and where to leave uncommitted changes. However if your project setup is complicated it may be more convenient to reuse the existing repo.

Comment: +1 Never used `-r` before, next time I find myself in this situation I'll be giving that a go.

Comment: When I worked with SVN I had a eclipse workspace for each branch of the project. I guess I could do that with mercurial too and maybe that is just the most pragmatic way to solve it.

Comment: @LasseL: You can choose which best suits your preference! :)

Comment: @LaurensHolst - method 1 is terrible wrong: cloned repo will be full mirror of source, using main-repo for returning changes is stupid. Method 2: a) `push -r` can't have parameter ".", only cset ID 2) N-heads branch can be pushed **only** with -f, merge have to be done before push

Comment: @LazyBadger: “Terribly wrong”, honestly? Please be more informed before making such a strong statement. First, I don’t see why you think a clone is a problem? It’s a DVCS, use that to your advantage. It’s hardlinked so if you’re worried about disk space consumption, don’t be. 2. `push -r` most definitely can have a parameter `.`. It is an alias for the current working copy’s changeset ID. And because you’re pushing only the head of the working copy, you are **not** pushing multiple heads so you don’t need to merge your work-in-progress feature branch.

Answer (score 3):

For this situation you can fix it by [rebasing](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) (which may need enabling in your configuration).

On your branch, update to the revision before the change-sets you want to move:

```
hg up -r<revison>
```

This assumes contiguous revisions need moving.

Create a new branch:

```
hg branch "TempWork"
```

Put a dummy commit onto it in order to get a new revision:

```
hg commit -m"New Branch"
```

Then perform the rebase from the first of the change-sets you want to move (it moves descendants automatically) and specify the new branch revision as the destination:

```
hg rebase -s<base revision> -d<new branch revision>
```

Then update back onto your main-line branch.

Comment: Ah you are right, I should have read it more clearly that he has made commits already.

Comment: This answer describes how to rebase your changes onto a new *named* branch. I think this is ugly; rebase is a history modifying operation, and named branches are typically not used for ad-hoc branching (precisely because they need to be set in advance and can not be retroactively added without modifying history). It is better and simpler to use anonymous branches or clones, optionally in combination with bookmarks.

Comment: @LaurensHolst Rebase is a commonly used and accepted mechanism. It works perfectly fine if the changes are local.

Comment: Thank you this looks to be the magic dust I was after. I was in a hurry and I already "fixed" my problem with backouts, but boy that was ugly and I broke the build :/ I'll try this approach next time.

Comment: @LasseL Actually if you can make use of anonymous branches without any issue, you can just `hg update -r` to a previous revision and continue working on a new "fork" of the code, as per Laurens' suggestion.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using rebase here. In a way I am going back and creating a branch, that I should have made if I had more foresight.

Comment: @LasseL I agree, there is nothing wrong with it. I've done it before when I realised I was on the wrong branch 3 change-sets too late. Modifying history locally is acceptable in my eyes, you just need to be aware of what modifies history and not to do it on pushed change-sets. Personally I don't think suggesting a history modifying solution warrants a down-vote, but hey ho - some people get quite strict with it all ;-)

Comment: I only voted you up. I'd accept both yours and Laurens' solution if there was a way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Fourth method: Using mq-patches**

- You have to have mq extension enabled and initiated for repo

On hotfix moment you

- convert feature-commits into set of mq-patches (`hg qimport`)
- Unapply all patches in set (`hg qpop -a`)
- Code hotfix, commit
- ...
- Finish and test hotfix on clean codebase
- Apply all patches in set (`hg qpush -a`), fix possible conflicts
- Convert patches back to changeset (`hg qfinish`)

Comment: Note that MQ is rather complicated and not really part of the standard DVCS flow. It’s a patch queue system built on top of DVCS. I would not recommend it for a novice user. Also it is a history modifying operation, for something that can just as well be handled by standard DVCS flow.